# How can I remove duplicate rows from one SQL Server database table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to delete the duplicate entries from one table of database (SQL).
I don't understand how do I do this?

Please help me to write a query for this problem.

**For e.g.-**

```
Name | mobileno | address

abc  | 99xxxx01 | India

abc  | 99xxxx01 | India

def  | 98xxxx02 | USA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #Duplicate
(
    Column1 VARCHAR(5),
    Column2 VARCHAR(20),
    Column3 VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #Duplicate VALUES('abc','99xxxx01','India'),('abc','99xxxx01','India'),('def','xxxx02','USA')

SELECT * FROM #Duplicate

;WITH CTE_Duplicate AS
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column1,Column2,Column3 ORDER BY Column1) AS Rno FROM #Duplicate
)
DELETE FROM CTE_Duplicate WHERE Rno = 2

SELECT * FROM #Duplicate
```

Comment: This would delete all your data if you'd feed that resultset to your delete..

Comment: Close but no cigar. This would only delete the first occurance of a duplicate. If you have a row 3 or 4 times as a duplicate you'd still have those. You should delete WHERE Rno > 1.

Comment: then change the WHERE Rno >= 2

Answer (score 0):

By using a common table expression to group your rows by what's duplicated and deleting all but one of them.

Have a look at this link: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/vivekssqlnotes/2013/12/29/deleting-duplicate-rows-using-cte/

So yours might look like this:

```
With cte_duplicate (name, mobileno, address, rownumber)
as (select name, mobileno, address, row_number()over(partition by name, mobileno, address) from your_table_name
)
delete from cte_duplicate where rownumber<>1
```

Comment: That won't work. There is no field in cte_duplicate called rownumber. Using the name "Rank" as an alias is also less than ideal.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHC, added the missing rownumber from the cte declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
with DelCTE as
(
select Name, MobileNo, Address, row_number() over(partition by Name, MobileNo, Address order by 1) as Row_Ord
from TableName
)
delete from DelCTE
where Row_Ord >1
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

```
;WITH numbered AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [dupe-column-list] ORDER BY [dupe-column-list]) AS _dupe_num 
    FROM [table-name] 
    WHERE 1=1 -- any where clause if required
)
DELETE FROM numbered WHERE _dupe_num > 1;
```

This should provide you with a solid result.

Comment: Deleted every row...

Answer (score -2):

Something like this

1. BEGIN TRAN
2. SELECT DISTINCT * INTO #TEMP
3. DELETE TABLE
4. INSERT INTO TABLE FROM #TEMP
5. SELECT * FORM TABLE --just to check all is good
6. -- COMMIT TRAN -- manually execute this if all is good with your data

Comment: Removing duplicates by dropping table is *BAD* idea, don't do this.

Comment: Dude, read the SQL Documentation DELETE is different from DROP. DELETE Table has the same result as DELETE FROM Table but it's actually faster.

Comment: If we are assuming we're talking MS SQL the FROM keyword is optional indeed, but claiming it's faster is a bit far fetched. It's pretty much like JOIN & INNER JOIN.

Comment: That's different, you might be right , but DELETE does not DROP the table.

Comment: My algorithm its't exactly like the other answers. Getting the unique records in a temp table, delete the source, insert unique lines. I don't get it

Comment: Correct, you aren't deleting the table, but you're deleting EVERYTHING inside it, resulting in a full table lock which could take quite a while in an active environment given you'd also have to rebuild all the indexes attached to it. This is not actually seen as best practice.

Comment: Whatever. I have just provided the general idea not a complete solution - this is what he asked for. Maybe he has only 3 lines in his table. At least you have a point, nimdil hasn't !

Comment: True, but you should always strive for best practice. Let's say this is a 200k row table & there's one duplicate.. Or this table has several foreign keys in other tables. This is a quick an dirty solution which could work in a test environment, but please don't ever do this in a production environment. You just wouldn't make any friends with it.

Comment: @AlexandruAliu I'm not in your head. When you write "Delete Table" then I'm not even sure what you mean. Deleting whole content of a table for that purpose is marginally better but still a long journey into bad practice zone. AFAIC -1.
General idea based on emptying a table is just bad general idea.